# Convert String to Data Type to store in Hash Table

Tags: powershell

I have something like this in my code:

```
 [MVPSI.JAMS.CredentialRights]::Submit
```

I'd like to be able to abstract it so I can change parts of it so effectively I want it to be a string:

```
$typeName = "MVPSI.JAMS.CredentialRights"
$function = "Submit"
```

However I can't then do this:

```
$typeName::$function
```

How do I do this?  To be fair I don't even know what these special `[]` and `::` are called in .Net\PowerShell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I don't even know what these special [] and :: are called in .Net\PowerShell

- `[...]` delimits a *type literal*; e.g. `[MVPSI.JAMS.CredentialRights]`
- `::` accesses a type's *static members*.

Note that both of these syntax forms are specific to *PowerShell*.

The alternative to using a type literal is to *cast a type name (string) to `[type]`*:

```
# The type name as a string.
$typeName = 'MVPSI.JAMS.CredentialRights'

# Get a reference to the type by its name.
$type = [type] $typeName

# The name of the static method to call.
$function = 'Submit'

# Call the static method on the type by its name.
# Note: Omitting '()' will output the method *signature*, including
#       its overloads.
$type::$function()
```

Comment: Mark this answer as correct. I believe that mklement0 is one of the staff from the [PowerShell Core 6 team](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell) and, based on his activity in the bug reports sections, he seems to have a lot of experience with PowerShell. (Also, his answer is better written than mine)

Comment: Thank you, @DaveF, I appreciate the comment, but to be clear: I'm just a fellow PowerShell user (and occasional contributor).

Answer (score 2):

Don't use quotes around $typeName because you are defining a string instead of referring to the `MVPSI.JAMS.CredentialRights` class. Use brackets instead.

```
$typeName = [MVPSI.JAMS.CredentialRights]
$function = "Submit"
$typeName::$function()
```

I believe that `::` is a static call to the function in the given class.